# Can jQuery TimeEntry work with higher than 24-hour format?

Tags: jquery, plugins, time

I am using the jQuery TimeEntry plugin, but I need to make it work with with more than 24-hour format. For examples I want to be able to select 90 hours. I found nothing about that in the docs. Is it possible?

Comment: You are gonna need to modify the plugin and lift the 12h/24h restriction. Notice the plugin is under a MIT license, so it's fine

Comment: It strongly uses a Date object, so it will not be easy to modify it. Can you recommend an alternative plugin, which allows selecting higher hours?